# NodeJs, ExpressJs, PassportJs, isAuthenticated returns null even though CORS is enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors, passport.js

I've got an app which has a front end/website serving logic on server A in Express, and backend logic with POST endpoints written in Express again on server B.

I've got withCredentials set to true on all my AngularJs methods which call the backend.

In the backend I've got this

```
var cors = require('cors');

var whitelist = 'http://serverA.com';
var corsOptions = {
    origin: whitelist,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    exposedHeaders: ['Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range'],
    credentials: true
};

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I try logging in from the client side and the login succeeds and redirects to the correct page but the **isAuthenticated** method on Passport returns false and it redirects me back to the login page.

What do you think the reason is that the session is not being stored on the client side. The cookie value seems to be set correctly (Chrome dev tools.)

Here is some client code. This is a middleware method used to protect pages for authenticated users.

```
function authenticate_func(req, res, next) {
    //return next();

    if (req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        console.log("Login Successful");
        return next();
    }

    console.log('Login Unsuccessful');
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

Here are middlewares I'm using and the order they are used in.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

require('/local_strategy')(passport, my_sql);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: please note that app.use in your question will not properly handle OPTIONS requests, which will likely be sent any time you have an Authorization header.

Comment: Can you provide us with the client-side code that checks whether or not the user is authenticated?

Comment: Updated the code, can you have a look now? It still doesn't work.